# Recording Screen Time for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time-management

I want an application that can record my screen time (like screen time in macOS). It should be able to show me how much time I have spent on each of the applications I have been using.

I have found one: [Automatic Recorder of Your Activities by jcrussell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/276/automatic-recorder-of-your-activities/), but it's not working, it shows an error. I suspect that its outdated.

Is there any other application or an extension like this one?
[image]

Any help is appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Shell version 4.4 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one such thing.
https://activitywatch.net/

it does the job, its pretty decent.